# Are we not supposed to be using the <main> element anymore?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Like most of my SO questions, this one stems from my inability to find up-to-date Google results.

It's been almost 3 years since `<main>` was accepted into the HTML5.1 spec. It seems to make perfect semantic sense to use:

```
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

But I see a lot of semantics-powered sites (like [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) <s>and [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/)</s>) that simply ignore the element, instead using something like:

```
<header></header>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <!--no ARIA role, nothing to semantically indicate "main" content-->
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

I feel like I've missed some conversation about how everyone needs to stop using `<main>` and Google's not helping me find that conversation. Was the element deemed unnecessary (i.e. clients don't really ever parse for it)?

Now it seems [IE never ended up supporting it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) (sans polyfill), but is that why folks aren't using it? The same sites I've seen use `div.main-wrapper` do LOTs of things that still require polyfills for IE. Why not still use the semantic benefits of `<main>`, which only requires a 1 line JS shiv and a `display:block`?

Comment: Just because IE never implemented doesn't mean a thing. Seems fine to me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Comment: Frankly, the position of the main landmark ought to be inferable from the other markup, and that was always the WHATWG spec editor's view, but one of the W3C editors, Steve Faulkner, forced though its introduction. And probably reasonably, as I don't think accessibility tools ever did try to infer it, but it does seem something of a kludge on the side of HTML5. So its adoption is understandably patchy. IE may not have supported it, but  there's definitely some support in Edge.

Comment: @Alohci Yeah, I heard Steve Faulkner had some pushback on it. I'd really like to see a resource that talks about HOW clients are using semantic markup, how they're parsing them. That would seem to be a much better way to teach folks to use them. Seems most folks just want to know how pass JAWS testing and get Google to list their content right. `article` and `nav` seem obvious, but `header`, `footer`, and `main` don't. Most people just use them as styling hooks.

Comment: I think @xdhmoore’s assessment is spot-on. (If it were an actual answer, I think it would be the right answer to accept.) Especially that part about “I would guess the problem isn't causing enough pain for the majority of users & developers”.

Comment: @Alohci My (very good friend) Steve Faulkner worked w/ the community & especially w/ multiple browser projects to get agreement on `main` **before he wrote the spec for it**. He [wrote the patch for `main` in WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/140341#) (I wrote the tests for that patch, & I committed it.) Talking w/ many people, then writing a spec & **writing code that implements the spec** & working with browser projects to land it is *exactly* how things should work. It is bad form to trash somebody for doing actual (hard) spec-wriiting work & writing browser code to make it real.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - I don't know Steve personally, but I have great respect for him and the work he has done. My misgivings are with the `<main>` element, not with him. We can see from the differences in the W3C and WHATWG specs that real problems remain. I'm no fan of the WHATWG definition , but I do think that W3C's  `<main>` could have been defined such that it fitted better with the other elements of HTML5.

Comment: @Alohci ok, fair enough. Personally I'm no fan of *any* of the html5 "semantic" elements eitherー article, section, etc. But my logic is that the horse already left the barn when we added those, and the lack of a `main` thus became an inconsistency. But I realize others don't see it that way, and reasonable people can respectfully disagree on this.

Comment: @Alohci "Steve Faulkner, forced though its introduction." is a mischaracterisation of the history. The majority of people involved in the discussions (including implementers) were in favour of the addition of the element. The one major exception was Hixie, the only thing I did was challenge his authority, and it worked because many others agreed to the challenging, in regards to this feature.

Comment: @SteveFaulkner - OK, my apologies. My recollection was faulty. I was more concerned with the oddity of the WHATWG definition than the W3C one at the time. I should have expressed more concern than I actually did about the W3C definition. It's probably too late now, but I did think that compromise between the two might have been possible, maybe on the lines of my penultimate paragraph [in my HTML5 Doctors comment](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/#comment-35571)

Comment: @Alohci, hey no problem, I made a recent foray into whatwg land to see if there could be some closer aligment of the 2 definitions (if not complete agreement), but I think that this is not a possibility https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/100

Comment: as a data point found that <main> is used on adactio.com and zeldman.com

Answer (score 3):

Answer: You should not avoid using the `main` element just because some other prominent sites/developers you run across are not using it.

There has been no conclusion among anybody anywhere to stop using `main` or to suggest to others that they should not be using it.

It’s not a *requirement* that you use it. But if you use it in a way that doesn’t cause the W3C validator to emit an error or warning, and in way you judge conveys the meaning/structure of your document as you the author intend—then go for it. That’s what it’s there for.

Comment: And you are taking a baby step towards wider adoption & meaningful client differentiated behavior.

Comment: What @xdhmoore said :)

Answer (score 3):

> (i.e. clients don't really ever parse for it)?

All major browsers except IE have implemented the parsing/styling and semantics mapping (role=main) for the main element, Edge has implemented. 3 years is not a long time in terms of uptake for a new element (although its usage is already much higher than some other new elements added years before it). Its use is steadily growing over time (you can grep the data from http://webdevdata.org if you are so inclined).

All major screen readers support main element semantics as part of landmark navigation.

> 63% of screenreader users sometimes/ often/ always use landmarks/ regions (so add them, or I’ll spank you). - [Bruce Lawson](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2015/reading-list-126/)

Comment: Well hey, Steve, thanks for responding. Considering a lot of folks now have jumped on the HTML5 bandwagon and seem to be pretty up-to-date (even bleeding edge) w/ a11y standards, why do you think some of those folks still seem to be hesitant to use `<main>`? I guess that's more to my question. --- I know many businesses haven't upgraded their sites to HTML5 simply to avoid using shivs for old IE. While short-sighted, that makes some sense. Using `<header>` and `<footer>` but not `<main>` (or at least `role=main`) *doesn't* make sense to me.

Comment: Hey @philtune, I don't see any hesitancy, usage and awareness takes time, the other HTML5 structural elements were around for 5 or more years [HTML5 draft in 2008 http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#sections] before main came along.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's a chicken/egg thing. There's not much point in using it in sites if clients aren't doing anything special with it. And there's not much point in some clients doing anything with it if adoption is low. And I would guess the problem isn't causing enough pain for the majority of users & developers.